# Angular & github

Tags: angular, function, github

I downloaded an existing angular project from github and run it in VsCode. But it is actually running in my browser. Login, signup and functions are not working. Is there any possibility to modify an existing angular project downloaded from Github and modify for my training project in vs code.
If it is possible can any one provide the steps to do so.

Comment: But there should be a running backend application that handles your webrequests... Isn't there another project included/referenced?

Comment: the back end file is also attached, but its not running because the  database is not thier in my sql server

Comment: You can make a "fake" login. I imagine the login use a service that call to API. Change the service using [of rxjs operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/of), e.g.: `login(user:any){return of({success:true,role:'admin'}).pipe(delay(300))}` Well, really I don't know about the object return the function login, but this is the idea

Answer (score 0):

Angular aplication it is only frontend part. For autorization work you need backand server and angular aplication need be connect with backand server.
Angular aplication take you login and password and send to backend. Backend server search you login in data base and check login, after send you response about auth state